# on application update ,need to migrate from database to sharedpreference

Tags: android, updates

In my current project's previous version we were using database for settings.
but for now we think that database is overhead for simple key value pairs
so we decided to use sharedpref for that.
Now the problem is how to handle to update functionality.
we are not using database so onUpgrade will not be work.

I am planing to do

```
ArrayList<String> databases = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(mContext.databaseList()));
if(databases.contains("dbname")){
    copyDataToSharedPref();
    mContext.deleteDatabase("dbname");
}
```

is there any simple way to handle this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637737/what-will-happen-to-the-sharedpreferences-on-update-an-android-app

Answer (score 2):

> is there any simple way to handle this?

Not exactly but it isn't difficult. Just do something similar to the following...

1. When your main / launcher `Activity` starts get it to check `SharedPreferences` for a specific key, example - a boolean "update_complete".
2. If the key doesn't exist, there are two possibilities. The first is it's a clean (new) install, the second is it's an update.
3. If the key *DOES* exist then the app has already been updated and the database data has already been transferred to `SharedPreferences` so proceed to run the app.
4. If the key *DOESN'T* exist then check to see if the database exists. If the database *DOESN'T* exist then this is a new installation. In that case just setup `SharedPreferences` as a new installation.
5. If the key *DOESN'T* exist but the database *DOES* exist, transfer the data from the database into `SharedPreferences`, delete the database then put the "update_complete" boolean into `SharedPreferences`.

I think that covers it.

Answer (score 0):

The Database entries will be there even after the App is updated (*if user doesn't clear data*). So in your situation I will:

- check if there are is any database and its not empty.
- if DB is there then read and create corresponding `SharedPreferences`.
- delete the database using `context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);`

I think that the `Application` class will be the best place to do so.

I am not sure if it is the best *(or worst `:P`)* method to do the same but I hope its useful.