# Android User data gets cleared after app update from google play

Tags: android, updates, google-play

I have an app where there is a website sign in page provided in a WebView. Once the user enters his details, the details are stored in SharedPreferences and the app communicates to a web API and receives a list of products depending on his credentials. The next time the user starts the app he doesn't need to sign in again and is directly taken to the page displaying the products. Everything worked fine and I uploaded the app on the play store.

After some time I made some changed to the app and uploaded the new version on the store. After I update the app the user if signed in should directly see the products page. But now after updation, he is shown the signin page again and even after sign in he gets a blank page instead of the products list.

I hope I am clear with my question.
Kindly help me, as this is my first app on the store.

Comment: With the updated version of your app, **You will surely get your data(in SharedPreference) clear** .. But the problem of not getting any product after sign in, must be due to some code only....Please verify it

Comment: @SweetWisherツ How do I check that? How can I debug it?

Comment: Are you able to get product list after sign in with you update app(not downloaded from playstore)?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ yes..If I run it directly from eclipse without downloading it from playstore everything works fine

Comment: @SweetWisherツ **You will surely get your data(in SharedPreference) clear** ! Are you sure? Any document references? This should not be happening from a developer prespective!

Comment: @user3146095 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637737/what-will-happen-to-the-sharedpreferences-on-update-an-android-app

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I have seen those links already. What can be the solution for this?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar yes its the same key and keystore

Comment: Then its probably a bug and and you need to report it to android google group.Shared Preferences or any app data shouldn't be getting cleared with app update as they have nothing to do with the update.