# SharedPreferences behavior on App Update

Tags: android

If an app update is released to devices and user updates the app, does the sharedPreference get reset/deleted?

What happens to the xml of sharedpreferences, is it deleted, re-created, or is unaltered?

Comment: It will remain same.

Comment: This has already been asked before. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637737/what-will-happen-to-the-sharedpreferences-on-update-an-android-app

Comment: thanks .didnt find that one on Google