# Does Updating to latest version of android application from play store clears shared preferences?

Tags: android

I am maintaining a sessions using Shared Preferences, when I update to latest version I am getting a login screen again.
Why? And Is there any solution to maintain a Shared Preferences data even after update of application?

Comment: What types are you saving in shared preferences ? Object or simple types ?

Comment: Shared preferences are not supposed to be cleared on update. From android M onwards, you could set android:allowBackup="true in the application level of your manifest to retain it.
Regarding the explanation to your question, you can read this
You could check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637972/1840795

Comment: **No** Shared preference will not clear automatically on updating app from play store. There might be some other issue. check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637737/what-will-happen-to-the-sharedpreferences-on-update-an-android-app

Comment: @MishaAkopov Its just a userId and boolean I am saving in shared preferences.

Comment: @NakulSudhakar I have added android:allowBackup="true" in my manifest.

Answer (score 0):

For maintaining session in your app you can use **sqlite** for storing session.
When you will use sqlite then it will not delete data you saved in it but for that you have to code well.

for the first time you can use **onCreate()** method of **sqliteopenheloper** class for creating table and

When you want to upgrade your app version then you have to use **onUpgrade()** methods of **SqliteOpenhelper** but you have to properly implement the **onUpgrade()** mehtod then only you will not loose your previous saved session.