# SharedPreferences lost after app update

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've been researching this issue for the whole day. Here are key points:

- SharedPreferences **should** be persistent when user does app update
- in my case, after updating the app, they are lost
- the issue is reproducable every time (I install old APK from Play Store and then `adb install -r new.apk` with the new (updated, signed, versionCode incremented) APK)

---

***8 hours later***

For test I changed SharedPrefs filename in `new.apk` (*SP2.xml*) and upon updating, the old SharedPrefs file from `old.apk` (*SP.xml*) **got deleted!** Here is adb shell output:

1. `adb install old.apk`
2. `adb shell "su -c 'ls /data/data/com.pkg.name/shared_prefs'"`:
   CRC.xml
3. `adb install -r new.apk`
4. `adb shell "su -c 'ls /data/data/com.pkg.name/shared_prefs'"`:
   CRC2.xml (CRC.xml missing!)

My SharedPreferences singleton class (init: `SharedPrefs.init(getApplicationContext());`):

```
public final class SharedPrefs {
    private static SharedPrefs sp;

    private SharedPrefs() {
    }

    public static void init(Context context) {
        if (sp == null)
            sp = context.getSharedPreferences("CRC2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static void saveString(String name, String value) {
        sp.edit().putString(name, value).apply();
    }

    public static String getString(String key, String defaultValue) {
      sp.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }
    ...
}
```

So basically I am loosing SharedPreferences and I have no clue why. Please help, any hint welcome!

Comment: is your app package name is same as previous? or you saving a serialized model class as string in shared preference?

Comment: Yes, package name is the same (otherwise I won't be able to update the app on Play Store). I have, however, changed the `<application>`s `android:label` (the name of the app).

Comment: Are you saving a serialized model class as string in shared preference?

Comment: What does your code look like which retrieves the Shared Preference object?

Comment: Try installing the application from your android studio and it will show you a dialog that it will uninstall the existing application. Just try it and you'll see the error message.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, no, just a few simple Strings.

Comment: @ZUNJAE, please check the update.

Comment: Few things. Why are you installing manually through adb? Secondly try this: `adb uninstall -k com.zun` and then `adb install com.zun` obv set the correct package name there.

Comment: May have a look at my question and their answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12637737/1306012

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you changed a property in the application section of the manifest file, this error will occur and 90% of the time, the shared pref data will be reset. This is what I found from my test installing the signed apk on top of my play store app. Not sure what will happen if the app was installed from the play store as an update, but am pretty sure the data would be lost in that case as well.

EDIT- I republished the application and tested multiple times. This in fact is the issue.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer considering it's not based on facts and lots of uncertainty.

Comment: I published on the play store and verified this. I have confirmed it today. Also, considering almost no one else has pointed this out, thought it was important to highlight it. Took me a long time to figure it out

Comment: Worked for me. You saved my day man, I was going insane. My application keeps offline data, and I was losing everything after updating to SDK 28.

Comment: How do you keep the error from happening? I have manifest data that needs to change with the update.

Comment: This is so bizarre and it's not documented anywhere! It's mind bogling!  To avoid this, I think JetPack's new DataStore might be a good solution.  Although you would have to encrypt the data yourself (and it's currently in alpha).

Comment: Is there a way to fix it?