# SharedPreferences data lost after app update

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How is it possible that the SharedPreferences data is lost due to an app update on Flutter.
After an update, some users reported that the data was no longer available.

After a lot of research, the only possible cause I could find was a change in the AndroidManifest (adding permission). -> [[Link]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51166728/14640355)

Is this possible and more importantly how can I avoid the error in the future?

Comment: That looks to be a very Android native specific issues. If you need to store something you really care about in the device, try to use a persistent SQL/NoSQL like file. With the right settings you can hold the information while doing updates and even while deleting the app

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Thanks, I'm already doing that. However, I would still like to be able to use SharedPreferences for "small settings".
And somehow I can't imagine that there isn't a solution for this, because otherwise SharedPreferences would be almost completely useless if the data is constantly being lost.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? im facing the same issue in flutter, but only on iOS devices